# Oracle INNER JOIN ON CASE WHEN condition

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, case-when

I have two subqueries I need to (inner) join on a column ("id"). Unfortunately, some of the values I am joining on have been altered somewhere before, so the `ON` condition of the `INNER JOIN` is supposed to be conditionally selected out of two, depending on the value of another column ("discriminator"). A simplified example follows:

Example result set query 1 (q1)

```
ID       DATA                DISCRIMINATOR
==========================================
1 1      Whatever            NULL
2AB      NULL                yes
4f-G     Could be anything   no
2CD      This one not        yes
2EEF     But this one        yes
11       And this            no
211      Last one            no
```

Example result set query 2 (q2)

```
ID       OTHERDATA     
====================
1 1      foo          
A B      bar               
EE F     foobar
G HH     barfoo
11       foofoo
```

If the discriminator is "yes" the IDs in q1 were altered by prepending '2' and removing all the whitespace, otherwise, they are the same. I still want to be able to correctly join the tables, and keep the ID from q2 in the join.

Expected Example Result

```
ID       DATA                OTHERDATA
==========================================
1 1      Whatever            foo
11       And this            foofoo
A B      NULL                bar
EE F     But this one        foobar
```

Can I somehow do a `CASE WHEN` in the `ON` condition? I tried the following

```
SELECT q2.id
    , q1.data
    , q2.otherdata
FROM ((...somequery...) q1
      INNER JOIN
      (...somequery...) q2
      ON CASE WHEN discriminator = 'yes' THEN TRIM(q1.id) = CONCAT('2', REPLACE(RTRIM(q2.id), ' ', ''))
          ELSE q1.id = q2.id
      END
     )
ORDER BY id
;
```

but I get a `missing keyword` error. I fiddled around but remain unable to correctly use `CASE WHEN` in the `ON` condition.

I know I could use a `UNION` to do something along the lines of

```
SELECT q2.id
    , q1.data
    , q2.otherdata
FROM ((...somequery...) q1 INNER JOIN (...somequery...) q2 
           ON q1.id = q2.id
               AND (discriminator <> 'yes' OR discriminator IS NULL)
         )
UNION
SELECT q2.id
    , q1.data
    , q2.otherdata
FROM ((...somequery...) q1 INNER JOIN (...somequery...) q2 
           ON TRIM(q1.id) = CONCAT('2', REPLACE(RTRIM(q2.id), ' ', ''))
               AND discriminator = 'yes'
          )
ORDER BY id
;
```

but this requires the subqueries being executed twice, doesn't it? I'd rather find a way that avoids that.

Is it possible to use a `CASE WHEN` statement in the `INNER JOIN` clause in a way that conditionally uses one out of two `ON` conditions? Or is there another elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
SELECT q2.id
    , q1.data
    , q2.otherdata
FROM ((...somequery...) q1
      INNER JOIN
      (...somequery...) q2
      ON (CASE WHEN discriminator = 'yes' AND TRIM(q1.id) = CONCAT('2', REPLACE(RTRIM(q2.id), ' ', '')) THEN 1
             WHEN (discriminator <> 'yes' OR discriminator IS NULL) AND q1.id = q2.id THEN 1
      END) = 1
     )
ORDER BY id
;
```